# How to format the date in the header of a DatePickerDialog in Android

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

Is it possible to format the date in the header of a DatePickerDialog in Android, if so how? I can't find any references to anyone who thought the current format looks horrible. I'm trying to change the default from:

Tues., 17 Oct. > Tues, 17 Oct

[image: DatePickerDialog]

Comment: which locale are you using?

Comment: I actually just left it as is, as it was wide spread through all other common apps so I didn't see the point in changing it then ;)

Comment: [Mine looks something like this](https://www.android-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/DatePickerDialog-theme-3.png)

Comment: @global_warming is that default for your app?

Comment: yep. Search google for datepickerdialog android.

Comment: I did, that's why I ended up here as I couldn't find a solution. It looks fine on lollipop but not nougat, both have same settings.